# Remove duplicate values of specific key in multidimensional array in PHP but remove the last?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
 Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10215484
            [descripcion] => Azucena viva de agua
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10315484
            [descripcion] => Azucena cortada fresca de agua
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10415484
            [descripcion] => Azucena cortada seca de agua
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10215484
            [descripcion] => Azucena viva de agua
        )
)
```

As you can see the first and last arrays are the same, so my code to remove the duplicates is like this

```
foreach ($my_array as $k => $v) {

    foreach ($my_arrays as $key => $value) {

        if ($k != $key && $v['clave'] == $value['clave']) {

            unset($my_array[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this works fine but I would like to remove the last array and let the first one to keep the order in which I added every array, so the result should be

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10215484
            [descripcion] => Azucena viva de agua
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10315484
            [descripcion] => Azucena cortada fresca de agua
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [clave] => 10415484
            [descripcion] => Azucena cortada seca de agua
        )
)
```

Because in the way I do it is removing always the first duplicates and the last always remains, some idea how to achieve this? I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the code you posted (the code with `foreach ($my_array as $k => $v) {`) give you the result you have at the bottom of your question?

Comment: @Goose no, with my code the first array is eliminated and the last keep in the array, I need to keep the same order as I'm adding each array and if there are duplicates it should remove the last and let the first in the array

Comment: I already solved my problem but SO dont let me to post my answer

Comment: Really? You should be able to post an answer I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like the code below:

```
$my_arrays = array_unique($my_arrays, SORT_REGULAR);

var_dump($my_arrays);
```

Comment: This is the wayI was looking for yo solve it, note that this doesn't work if the `descripcion` is different and `clave` the same, both value keys must be the same, this is the answer I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a slight change in your code. Unset the second array '$my_arrays' and use it.

```
foreach ($my_array as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($my_arrays as $key => $value) {
        if ($k != $key && $v['clave'] == $value['clave']) {
           unset($my_arrays[$k]);
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_arrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It begins with an array. The first time an duplicate is encountered, it's value is added to the array. The second, third, etc. time it's encountered, it's removed.

```js
$dup = array();

foreach ($my_array as $k => $v) {

    foreach ($my_arrays as $key => $value) {

        if ($k != $key && $v['clave'] == $value['clave']) {

            if ( in_array( $value['clave'], $dup) ) {
                unset($my_array[$k]);  
            } else {
              $dup[] = $value['clave'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code returns `Array
(
    [0] => 50202301
)`, I want to keep my data as you see in the original array I mean with its keys and values, same structure but eliminating the last duplicates

Comment: Sorry? `$dup` is used to find duplicates, not to output the array without any duplicates. After running this code, display `$my_array`. All of the duplicates should be gone.

Comment: Yes, it delete duplicates but is not deleting the last but the first one, I need to delete the last ones of each duplicate

Comment: @Ashe How about now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$array = array(
  array('clave' => 10215484 , 'descripcion' => 'Azucena viva de agua'),
  array('clave' => 10215484 , 'descripcion' => 'Azucena viva de agua bentin'),
  array('clave' => 10215484 , 'descripcion' => 'Azucena viva de agua corva'),
  array('clave' => 10215484 , 'descripcion' => 'Azucena viva de agua')
);

$new_array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [clave] => 10215484
        [descripcion] => Azucena viva de agua
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [clave] => 10215484
        [descripcion] => Azucena viva de agua bentin
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [clave] => 10215484
        [descripcion] => Azucena viva de agua corva
    )
)
```

Comment: I solved my problem before you posted this but this is better than I did but another user gave this answer before you did , thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ashe. Okay. Nice to hear.  Welcome :)